# How to open input file, C++ on visual studio community 2015?

Tags: c++, fstream

Does anyone know why the file isn't opening? I also tried just putting "infile.txt" and placing it in the folder of the program and also the debug folder but the ways I used to check for open error both triggered meaning that it could not open. I know I can hard code the location but I don't want to.

I heard you should do `stringobj.c_str()` but I don't know if that's accurate?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;

    string fileloc = "infile.txt";

    infile.open(fileloc);


    if (!infile)
    {
        cout << "open fail 1" << endl;
    }

    bool fail = infile.fail();
    if (fail)
    {
        cout << "open fail 2";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Place the file in the directory in Debugging > Working Directory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note that the directory structure (at least for VS2013) is

```
<base>
   - Solution Directory
     - Debug
     - Release
     - Project Directory
       - Debug
       - Release
```

The program by default runs in the project directory (even though it is built to the solution/debug directory).

If you accepted the default naming convention when starting your project, you should be putting your file in the "Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1" directory, not "Projects\ConsoleApplication1"

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Check your working directory in Project Settings -> Debugging. Make your file available there.

Answer (score 2):

First, the documentation for the signature of

```
std::ifstream::open( const char * filename, ios_base::openmode mode=ios_base::in)
```

does indicate it requires a const char *, exactly what std::string::c_str() provides. However, there is an overload for open which accepts a const str &, which means it works the same way for both on most implementations.

Otherwise, what you're grappling with is known as the current working directory (or cwd). Apparently you're not sure where THAT directory is. It may be different while you run the debugger on Visual Studio than it is when you run your program from the command line, and it may be different in various IDE's.

I'm not sure why you want to ensure your program only opens a file by name in the current directory, and not give the full path, but...

You may want to inquire what the current working directory is, so you can solve the mystery wherever you try this. In my Visual Studio 2015, the directory ends up being the directory ABOVE debug, but that depends entirely on how your project is configured, and we can't see that out here.

So, try:

```
std::string cwd = getcwd( NULL, 0 );
```

This requires a header `<direct.h>` on Windows in Visual Studio, but it will give you the directory you're trying to figure out.

Comment: Why would you want to hardcode the absolute path of a resource file?

Comment: Not sure if you responded to the right answer, but in the answer I gave, the absolute path of a resource file is not hard coded. Indeed, the OP did not want to hard code the path, but in my own question about that point I was not asking why the OP didn't want to hard code the full path, just why not specify the full path. Using the getcwd function would allow for one to fashion a full path based on cwd, which the OP was having difficulty finding, leading to the option of displaying an error with that full path.

Answer (score 1):

with

```
string fileloc = "infile.txt";
```

if you put infile.txt in the same folder of the cpp file, it should be fine.

btw I delete your first line

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

I use cygwin console, may have minor diff

Comment: The location of the cpp file and the resultant executable and that executable's working directory are independent things.

Answer (score 0):

For my issue - i was stuck at loading image by opencv - i was wrong to place directory with jpg in the root of the C++ project

WRONG:

[image]

CORRECT:
[image]